# Mathematical riddle - how to solve numerically in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

So the riddle is:

John has written down `k` sequential odd numbers: `n{1}, n{2}, ..., n{k-1}, n{k}` (where `n{2} = n{1} + 2` and so on). We know that:

- The sum of the first four numbers is a fourth power of some prime number (so `n{1} + n{2} + n{3} +  n{4} = p{1}` where `p{1}^4` is a prime number.
- The sum of the last five numbers is a fourth power of some prime number (so `n{k} + n{k-1} + n{k-2} +  n{k-3} + n{k-4}= p{2}^4` where `p{1}` is a prime number.

The question is - how many numbers have been written down (`k=?`).

Below is my attempt to solve it in Java:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Set;

//precalculate prime numbers
public class PrimeSieve {


 public static boolean[] calculateIntegers(int N) { 


    // initially assume all integers are prime
    boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[N + 1];
    for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
        isPrime[i] = true;
    }

    // mark non-primes <= N using Sieve of Eratosthenes
    for (int i = 2; i*i <= N; i++) {

        // if i is prime, then mark multiples of i as nonprime
        // suffices to consider mutiples i, i+1, ..., N/i
        if (isPrime[i]) {
            for (int j = i; i*j <= N; j++) {
                isPrime[i*j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return isPrime;
  }
}
```

The solving class:

```
public class Solver {
    static boolean[] isPrime = PrimeSieve.calculateIntegers(100000);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int minNumberCount = 5;
        int maxNumberCount = 2000;
        int startInt = 2;
        int endInt = 1000000;

        for (int numberCount = minNumberCount; numberCount < maxNumberCount+1; numberCount++) {
            System.out.println("Analyzing for " + numberCount + " numbers");

            int[] numbers = new int[numberCount];

            //loop through number sets
            for (int firstNum = startInt; firstNum < endInt; firstNum+=2) {

               //populate numbers array
                for(int j=0; j<numberCount; j++){
                    numbers[j] = firstNum + j*2;
                }

                long bottomSum=0;
                long topSum=0;

                //calculate bottom sum
                for(int iter=0; iter<4; iter++){
                    bottomSum+=numbers[iter];
                }

                //calculate top sum
                for(int iter=numberCount-1; iter>numberCount-6; iter--){
                    topSum+=numbers[iter];
                }

                //check if the sums match the sulution criteria
                if(checkPrime(quadRoot(bottomSum)) && checkPrime(quadRoot(topSum))){
                    System.out.println("SOLUTION!");

                    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                        System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
                    }
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }       
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkPrime(int i){
        return isPrime[i];
    }

    private static boolean checkPrime(double i){
        return ((i % 1) == 0) && checkPrime((int) i);
    }

    private static double quadRoot(long n){
        return Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(n));
    }

 }
```

Using this algorithm with the assumed parameters (max `k=2000`, max `n{1}=100000`) - I've found no solution. My question is: are the parameter assumptions wrong (no solution in this range), or do I have some algorithmic/numeric error and that is the reason I've found no solution?

EDIT: sorry - my mistake - it should be ODD instead of EVEN.

Comment: Your statement of the problem is rather sloppy; for example you assert that the sum of the first four numbers must be equal to the fourth power of a prime number but have `= p{1}` on the rhs where `p{1}` is a prime number.  Surely that should be `= p{1}^4` ?  If this inattention to detail has made it into your code I'm not surprised it's finding no solutions.

Comment: You are saying that `n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 = p1`. If `n1, n2, n3, n4` are all even then the sum of them will be even. Hence p1 **cannot** be a prime number, since the only even prime number is 2.

Comment: You don't need to use an array at all. The sum of the first 4 is n + n +2 + n + 4 + n + 6 or `4 * n + 12` This means p^4 is even so p must be even and there is only 1 even prime....

Comment: And if you mean `n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 = p1^4`. Then `p1^4` still has to be even, and since the product of two odd numbers is odd, then p1 can only be 2, if p1 is prime. Hence, `n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 = 16`. But there are no consecutive even numbers n1,n2,n3,n4 that sum up to 16. Hence the problem obviously does not have a solution, and it doesn't take a computer to calculate that...

Comment: Sorry, already corrected this: p{1}^4

Comment: in your program int startInt = 1; now or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is still easier to solve this directly than to write a program.

The first sum is even so it must be 16 (since 2 is the only even prime). The first four numbers are therefore 1,3,5,7.

The sum of five consecutive odd numbers is 5 times the middle number hence must be divisible by 5. Since it is a fourth power of a prime it must be 625 and the last five numbers are therefore 121,123,125,127,129

It is now an easy task to determine k=65

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, your riddle has no solution.

Let's suppose there was a solution, then `n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 == p1^4` . We know that n1,n2,n3,n4 are even from the definition of the riddle and therefore as a sum of even numbers, `n1 + n2 + n3 + n4` is even as well. This leads us to the fact that `p1^4` is even. We know that a multiplication of two odd numbers results only an odd number, hence `p1^4 = p1 * p1 * p1 * p1` means that p1 must be an even number. However, p1 is prime. The only prime number which is also even is 2. It's easy to see that there are no four consecutive even numbers that sum up to 16 and therefore p1 is not prime. This contradicts the assumption that p1 is a prime, hence, no solution.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only even numbers, the sum of those is an even number. If I understood correctly, your sum has to be the result of the fourth power of a prime number. Considering the sum is an even number, the only number to satisfy your condition is 16 (2*2*2*2), where 2 is a prime number, so your sum of 4 even number has to be 16. Now, if you're certain there's a sequence, then the sum is computed by adding the first and the last number in the sequence, then multiplying the result with the number of elements in the sequence, and dividing the result of the multiplication by 2. For example, 2+4+6+8=(2+8)*4/2=10*4/2=20. Similarly, for your example, n{1}+n{2}+...+n{k}=(n{1}+n{k})*k/2
On a side note, your smallest sum of 4 even numbers (20), the example I used, is already above your only 4th power of the prime number (16), so yes, there is no valid example in your sequence.

I hope this made some sense